# Browser detection script and if statement

Tags: javascript

I am using following script to check that a browser is firefox and it is mac os. Right now i am on linux chrome but still the following if statement works. http://jsfiddle.net/RjyW6/3/

```
var BrowserDetect = {
    init: function () {
        this.browser = this.searchString(this.dataBrowser) || "An unknown browser";
        this.version = this.searchVersion(navigator.userAgent)
            || this.searchVersion(navigator.appVersion)
            || "an unknown version";
        this.OS = this.searchString(this.dataOS) || "an unknown OS";
    },
    searchString: function (data) {
        for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
            var dataString = data[i].string;
            var dataProp = data[i].prop;
            this.versionSearchString = data[i].versionSearch || data[i].identity;
            if (dataString) {
                if (dataString.indexOf(data[i].subString) != -1)
                    return data[i].identity;
            }
            else if (dataProp)
                return data[i].identity;
        }
    },
    searchVersion: function (dataString) {
        var index = dataString.indexOf(this.versionSearchString);
        if (index == -1) return;
        return parseFloat(dataString.substring(index+this.versionSearchString.length+1));
    },
    dataBrowser: [
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Chrome",
            identity: "Chrome"
        },
        {   string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "OmniWeb",
            versionSearch: "OmniWeb/",
            identity: "OmniWeb"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "Apple",
            identity: "Safari",
            versionSearch: "Version"
        },
        {
            prop: window.opera,
            identity: "Opera",
            versionSearch: "Version"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "iCab",
            identity: "iCab"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "KDE",
            identity: "Konqueror"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Firefox",
            identity: "Firefox"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "Camino",
            identity: "Camino"
        },
        {       // for newer Netscapes (6+)
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Netscape",
            identity: "Netscape"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "MSIE",
            identity: "Explorer",
            versionSearch: "MSIE"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Gecko",
            identity: "Mozilla",
            versionSearch: "rv"
        },
        {       // for older Netscapes (4-)
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Mozilla",
            identity: "Netscape",
            versionSearch: "Mozilla"
        }
    ],
    dataOS : [
        {
            string: navigator.platform,
            subString: "Win",
            identity: "Windows"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.platform,
            subString: "Mac",
            identity: "Mac"
        },
        {
               string: navigator.userAgent,
               subString: "iPhone",
               identity: "iPhone/iPod"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.platform,
            subString: "Linux",
            identity: "Linux"
        }
    ]

};
BrowserDetect.init();
console.log(BrowserDetect.browser);
console.log(BrowserDetect.OS);
if((BrowserDetect.browser)==="Firefox" && (BrowserDetect.OS)==="Mac");
                      {
                            alert('this');
                      }
```

any help?

Comment: Why does your app need browser detection? Often it's capability detection that an app needs. Just checking that actual browser detection is what you need.

Comment: (Also fails for IE11 as well as the other usual edge cases. Don't browser-sniff. Every time you `navigator.userAgent`, God kills a kitten.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the semicolon:

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------v
if((BrowserDetect.browser)==="Firefox" && (BrowserDetect.OS)==="Mac");
{
  alert('this');
}
```

Otherwise the *if* block appears to be empty, i.e. this is what the computer sees:

```
if((BrowserDetect.browser)==="Firefox" && (BrowserDetect.OS)==="Mac") {
  // Do nothing
}
{
  // Just another block
  alert('this');
}
```

Comment: my editor windows was in horizontal scroll and i wasnt able to seee it

Comment: @Humanlove By the way, you don't need the parentheses around `BrowserDetec.browser/OS`.

Answer (score 2):

You have `;` at the wrong place.

Remove `;` from the end of `if((BrowserDetect.browser)==="Firefox" && (BrowserDetect.OS)==="Mac");`

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got an addition semicolon causing problems. Try this:

```
if((BrowserDetect.browser)==="Firefox" && (BrowserDetect.OS)==="Mac")  // this had the semicolon
{
  alert('this');
}
```